# Pipenv Django installation: Failed parsing requirement

Tags: python-3.x, django, macos, pipenv

I'm new to pipenv and installations in Mac Terminal. I was trying to install Django through pipenv and was getting the following error:

```
File "/Users/sidm/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 969, in _parse_name_from_line
    "Failed parsing requirement from {0!r}".format(self.line)
pipenv.vendor.requirementslib.exceptions.RequirementError: Failed parsing requirement from u'--python3.7'
```

I'd be so grateful if someone helps me resolving this issue.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pip install --user django
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use a version of python 3.6 or higher to install django.

ref: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/install/#:~:text=Python%203%20is%20recommended.,of%20Python%203%20is%20recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/install/#:%7E:text=Python%203%20is%20recommended.,of%20Python%203%20is%20recommended).